# How to convert string to Date in Angular2 \ Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a new Date object, with a specific date.
I thought of converting it from a specific string,  for example:

```
let dateString = '1968-11-16T00:00:00'
```

How can I convert it to a date object **in typescript**?

**Update:**

I'm asking for a solution **in Typescript** and not in Javascript, and in **Angular2**, not AngularJS (1.x)

Comment: @AravindSivam I asked in typescript, not javascript

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tryed, didn't find anything relevant (abviously)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please notice I was asking for a solution in Typescript (not Javascript)  for Angular2 (not AngularJS 1.x which is very different). You can read it both in the question title or in my update.

Comment: JavaScript is a subset of TypeScript. Not everything needs to be different just because you're using TypeScript ;-)

Comment: @cookya Typescript is a superset of javascript. There is not separate method for typescript

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can use date filter to convert in date and display in specific format.

**In .ts file (typescript):**

```
// variables used in html
let dateString = '1968-11-16T00:00:00' 
let newDate = new Date(dateString);

// format date in typescript
getFormatedDate(date: Date, format: string) {
    const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
    return datePipe.transform(date, format);
}

// Convert date to user timezone
const localDate: Date = this.convertToLocalDate('01/01/2021');

convertToLocalDate(responseDate: any) {
    try {
        if (responseDate != null) {
            if (typeof (responseDate) === 'string') {
                if (String(responseDate.indexOf('T') >= 0)) {
                    responseDate = responseDate.split('T')[0];
                }
                if (String(responseDate.indexOf('+') >= 0)) {
                    responseDate = responseDate.split('+')[0];
                }
            }

            responseDate = new Date(responseDate);
            const newDate = new Date(responseDate.getFullYear(), responseDate.getMonth(), responseDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
            const userTimezoneOffset = newDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

            const finalDate: Date = new Date(newDate.getTime() - userTimezoneOffset);
            return finalDate > Util.minDateValue ? finalDate : null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return responseDate;
    }
}
```

**In HTML:**

```
{{dateString |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

Below are some formats which you can implement :

**Backend:**

```
public todayDate = new Date();
```

**HTML :**

```
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="MM/dd/yyyy">[{{todayDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}]</option>
<option value="EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy">[{{todayDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy'}}]</option>
<option value="EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a">[{{todayDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a'}}]</option>
<option value="EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a">[{{todayDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a'}}]</option>
<option value="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a">[{{todayDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a'}}]</option>
<option value="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a">[{{todayDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a'}}]</option>
<option value="MMMM d">[{{todayDate | date:'MMMM d'}}]</option>   
<option value="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss">[{{todayDate | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'}}]</option>
<option value="h:mm a">[{{todayDate | date:'h:mm a'}}]</option>
<option value="h:mm:ss a">[{{todayDate | date:'h:mm:ss a'}}]</option>      
<option value="EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a">[{{todayDate | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}]</option>
<option value="MMMM yyyy">[{{todayDate | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}]</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: @sandip-full-stack-developer, I'm curious why you use `todayDate = new Date(Date.parse(Date()))` instead of `todayDate = new Date()`. Both will return different result?

Comment: This doesn't appear to show how to format a date with a format string on backend? i.e "'MM/dd/yyyy'"

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper I have updated logic to convert from typescript using datepipe