# Convert string to timestamp Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, date, timestamp

There's an easy way to convert a string from an input to a timestamp?

For example... I got this:

```
"5/4/2018 11:49:01"
```

how do I convert that to this format?

```
"1522928905"
```

Comment: I don't think it's exactly a duplicate, but this is similar and may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202250/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-angular2-typescript/43202323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the getTime() function of the date object. 
For example:

```js
let date = new Date("5/4/2018 11:49:01");
console.log(date.getTime());
```

getTime() returns the time in milliseconds, if you want the time in seconds just divide the result with 1000.